# placing a text right beside another text

Tags: android, xml

I have designed a simple layout in android where I needed to place an element right beside another element. On attempting to do that the textview jumps below the textview that is supposed to be at the side of it. Here is my approach

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
            android:text="Up"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

I want this textview to be placed beside the above textview
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/1"
            android:text="Two"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in assistance

Comment: Enclose them with horizontal `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LinearLayouts` have and `orientation` property, that indicates how they elements will grow.
You can nest `LinearLayout` inside another one if you want to mix orientations, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
            android:text="Up"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Two"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                          android:id="@+id/1"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
                          android:text="Up"
                          android:textSize="15sp" />

                    <TextView
                          android:id="@+id/2"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/1"
                          android:text="Two"
                          android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/movieImage"
                android:text="Up"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/1"
                android:text="Two"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```